# Huge Time Lag of Addressables Package Method in Unity Engine

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, assetbundle, addressables

Within the unity project,
we are managing asset bundles using addressable packages.

However, there is a huge time lag when getting the download size using `Addressables.GetDownloadSizeAsync(string)`.

Does this happen if the number of bundles managed is large?
If it does, is there any way to fix it?

Currently, one label manages about 300 bundles.

```
// Asset Bundles Download Size
AsyncOperationHandle<long> getDownloadSize = Addressables.GetDownloadSizeAsync(BundleManager.GetInstance.DownloadKey);
return getDownloadSize;
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.